# I am getting a Parser Error in browser when trying to access my app from remote server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, webforms, remote-server

New to programming and this is my first application that I am attempting to deploy on a server.

The application runs locally in VisualStudio. However, when accessing it directly from the server I am getting a "Parser Error". I did not touch the Global pages at all.

This is the error text I received in the browser:

> Parser Error
> Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'Forms.Global'.
>
> Source Error:
> Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="Forms.Global" Language="C#" %>

Things that I have tried:

- Make sure that the "Global.asax" file and the "Global.asax.cs" files
  are both present in the root directory of your application.
- Make sure that the namespace in the "Global.asax.cs" file matches the
  namespace specified in the "Inherits" attribute of the "Global.asax"
  file.
- Make sure that the class name in the "Global.asax.cs" file matches
  the class name specified in the "Inherits" attribute of the
  "Global.asax" file.
- Double-check that the class "Global" is defined in the
  "Global.asax.cs" file.
- Try rebuilding your application to ensure that all necessary
  dependencies and files are included.

Comment: Check that the project output path (project properties / Build) is set to bin and not bin\Release or bin\Debug, for some reason IIS always accesses the libraries from the bin directory (and won't look up for subdirectories).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you deploying as a web site, or web site application? If you deploy as a "application", then you don't need the source code to be deployed on the site. This then assumes you been working and opening your site as file-open->project. (and not file->open web site).

So, if you using a "application", then you want to use the publish feature, and you can even publish to a local folder (say c:\test\web). That resulting publish folder is what you place on the server. So, depending on your "kind" of site site you created, your deployment will result in NO .cs files or source code required.

While a web site "application" means that a full re-publish is required even for one small code change, the control and additional features you have for the project outweighs this one downside.

So, I suggest you use the publish option for your site. You can thus publish to a local folder. (even zip the file after). It is that published site you transfer to the server.

You also don't mention if a database is involved, and that will often mean your connection strings have to be changed, or at least "different" in the web config vs release.web.config.

so, very imporant here:

are you using a asp.net web site

or

are you using a asp.net web site application?

As noted, with the application option, then you don't have nor need the source code (code behind) files on the server. But, as noted, this will depend on how your project was created.

web site:

file->open web site   (that means a asp.net web site).

However, if you been using:

file->open project?

That means a asp.net web site "application".

If you are using the 2nd option, then you want to use the publish option to create that site that you THEN move/copy/deploy/place on the target server.

So, that means you use this option to build's the site before deploy:

[image]